# Splitting a Dictionary of tuples into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I have created a dictionary with the piece of code:

```
    dat[r["author_name"]] = (r["num_deletions"], r["num_insertions"], 
r["num_lines_changed"], r["num_files_changed"], r["author_date"])
```

I want to then take these dictionary and create a panda with columns

```
author_name | num_deletions | num_insertions | num_lines_changed |num_files changed | author_date
```

I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dat.iteritems()),
                      columns=['author_name',"num_deletions", "num_insertions", "num_lines_changed", 
                              "num_files_changed",  "author_date"])
```

But it does not work since it is reading the key and the tuple of the dictionary as only two columns instead of six. So how can I take each of the five entries in the tuple and divide them into their own columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the key and value at the same nesting level:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(key,)+val for key, val in dat.items()], 
                  columns=["author_name", "num_deletions",
                           "num_insertions", "num_lines_changed", 
                           "num_files_changed",  "author_date"])
```

You could also use

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ["author_name", "num_deletions",
              "num_insertions", "num_lines_changed", 
              "num_files_changed",  "author_date"]
```

Which seems to be a bit faster if you have roughly 10,000 rows or more.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['author_name', 'num_deletions', 'num_insertions', 'num_lines_changed',
                               'num_files_changed','author_date'])
```